# Prove that, given positive integers m and n, if m | n then 2^m − 1 | 2^n − 1. In particular, deduce that if 2^n − 1 is prime then n is prime.

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers, divisibility

I think I have the first part of the proof down but I would like to double check that my logic works:

m|n $\Leftrightarrow$ n = k*m $\Rightarrow$ $2^n-1 = 2^{km}-1$ 
$2^{km}-1$=$(2^m)^k-1^k=(2^m-1)((2^m)^{k-1}+\ldots + 1)$ 
So $2^n-1=(2^m-1)((2^m)^{k-1}+\ldots + 1)$.

Therefore, because m|n, we know $2^m-1|2^n-1$.

Does this proof work? Also, if it does, how do I deduce that if $2^n − 1$ is prime then n is prime? And does "deduce" mean prove that this is also true?

Comment: How could $(2^m)^k-1^k=(2^m-1)(2^{m-1}+1)$ hold?

Comment: @Paul I'm sorry, I mis-typed the expansion I am using. I meant to use the fact that $x^n-y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$

Comment: @Bryyo357 Using polynomial long division like that works, except you have to correct your working. But induction is also easy, as I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Induction is the easy way to go here. Show that if $(2^m-1)| (2^{km}-1)$ for some $k$, then $(2^m-1)| (2^{(k+1)m}-1)$.

$2^{(k+1)m}-1 = 2^{km}\cdot 2^m - 1 = (2^{km} - 1)2^m + 2^m - 1$

Can you complete the proof?

For the last part, consider the contrapositive of the statement.

Comment: Using our inductive hypothesis, we can say
$(2^{km}-1)2^m+2^m-1=r(2^m-1)2^m+(2^m-1)=(2^m-1)(r*2^m+1)$
And from that we know that (2^m-1)|(2^{(k+1)m}-1) because (2^m-1)|(2^m-1)(r*2^m+1) and so it's proved by induction?

And the contrapositive would be "If $2^n-1 is not prime then n is not prime", correct? Where would I go from there?

Comment: Yes, you have the induction proof correct, except you have to verify the base case for $k=1$, but that's trivial. For the latter part, if $2^n-1$ is prime, then there are no factors other than $1$ and $2^n-1$ that divide it. Which means that no $m$ exists such that $(2^m-1)|(2^n-1)$ and $1 <m < n$. Now the contrapositive of the statement you just showed is $(2^m-1)\nmid (2^n-1) \implies m \nmid n$. Since the first condition holds for every $1 < m < n$, you can assert that for every such $m$, $m \nmid n$. Isn't it now trivial to conclude primality of $n$?

Answer (score 0):

Your proof works well.

If $n$ is not prime, then $n=k\cdot m$ for some $n>m>1$. But then $2^m-1$, which is bigger than $1$ and less than $2^n-1$, divides $2^n-1$ (as you have just shown), so $2^n-1$ wouldn't be prime.

Comment: For the second part, you're saying that n composite => $2^n-1$ composite. Is that the same thing as showing $2^n-1$ prime => n is prime?

Comment: Yes. Composite natural number is a natural number greater than one that is not prime.